# Page index is not working

Tags: c#

Help me ..my page index is not working in visual studio.
my page load is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                CustomerView.DataSource = Customer.GetAll();
                CustomerView.DataBind();
            }
        }

protected void CustomerView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int newPageNumber = e.NewPageIndex + 1;
            CustomerView.DataSource = Customer.GetAll();
            CustomerView.DataBind();
        }
```

what am i doing wrong my page index in not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I think you have to set the GridView's PageIndex property manually.

```
protected void CustomerView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    CustomerView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    CustomerView.DataSource = Customer.GetAll();
    CustomerView.DataBind();
}
```